# Culling list to find greatest non-intersecting members in Python

Tags: list, python, list-comprehension, intersection

Each element in the list L is a tuple of the form (fields, size). For example

```
L = [ (['A','B'], 5), (['A'], 6), ('C', 1)]
```

I would like to cull the list so it only contains non-intersecting members, and each member that remains was greater than any other members it may have intersected. So the example list L would be reduced to

```
L = [ (['A'], 6), ('C', 1)]
```

Currently I have it implemented like so:

```
def betterItem(x, y):
    return (x != y and
            set(x[0]) & set(y[0]) and
            x[1] > y[1])

for i in range(len(L)-1):
    L[:] = [x for x in L for y in L if betterItem(x, y)]
```

Is there a better/faster/more Pythonic way of doing this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks fairly pythonic to me. Is what you have there too slow? You could try starting by finding pairs of indexes which match between list members and then only call betterItem on those indices to reduce them.

Comment: @Lattyware Done, thanks for the reminder... my SO visits tend to be very occasional and I forget to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [(['A','B'], 5), (['A'], 6), (['C'], 1)]

# sort by descending value
L.sort(key=lambda s:s[1], reverse=True)

# keep track of what members have already occurred
seen = set()

# Cull L - ignore members already in `seen`
# (Because it is presorted, already-seen members must have had a higher value)
L = [seen.update(i) or (i,j) for i,j in L if seen.isdisjoint(i)]
```

results in

```
[(['A'], 6), (['C'], 1)]
```

(This list comprehension uses a bit of sleight-of-hand: `seen.update` always returns `None`, and `None or x` always returns `x` - so `seen.update(i) or (i,j)` returns the tuple `(i,j)` with the side-effect of updating the seen-member list.)

This should be O(n log n) due to the `sort`, instead of your O(n^2).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, but it adds a bit too much complexity for the speed gain (not going to have massive lists to perform this on). Thanks.